# Create nested dictionaries in a for loop without overwriting python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested, overwrite

I am trying to build a webscrapper which takes certain informations based on html tags and puts them into dictionaries.

I have a first function which scrapes a website and returns a dictionnary like the following:

```
{"Url": "www.test1.de", "Document Title": "test1", "Releaes Date": "January 1, 2020",...}
```

My second function gets as input a list of links and should loop through these links with the first function, then kind of append these dictionnaries to one big one.

```
def create_dict(link_list):
    all_data_dict = {}
    count = 0
    for link in link_list:

        all_data_dict[count] = scrape_doc_info(link,tag_list, selector_dict) # this function returns the dictionnary mentioned above
        print(all_data_dict)
        count +=1
        
    return(all_data_dict)
```

I would like to have the following out come.

```
all_data_dict = { 0 = {"Url": "www.test1.de", "Document Title": "test1", "Releaes Date": "January 1, 2020",...}, 
1 = {"Url": "www.test2.de", "Document Title": "test2", "Releaes Date": "January 2, 2022",...},..., 20 = {"Url": "www.test20.de", "Document Title": "test20", "Releaes Date": "January 20, 2200",...}}
```

But my code always overwrites the values of the keys with values of the last link. So if I loop through 20 links, I will always have the values of the last link for each key:

```
all_data_dict = { 0 = {"Url": "www.test20.de", "Document Title": "test20", "Releaes Date": "January 20, 2200",...}, 
    1 = {"Url": "www.test20.de", "Document Title": "test20", "Releaes Date": "January 20, 2200",...},..., 20 = {"Url": "www.test20.de", "Document Title": "test20", "Releaes Date": "January 20, 2200",...}}
```

The console output of the print argument is as follows:

First loop:

```
all_data_dict = { 0 = {"Url": "www.test1.de", "Document Title": "test1", "Releaes Date": "January 1, 2020",...}
```

Second loop:

```
all_data_dict = { 0 = {"Url": "www.test2.de", "Document Title": "test2", "Releaes Date": "January 2, 2022",...}, 
1 = {"Url": "www.test2.de", "Document Title": "test2", "Releaes Date": "January 2, 2022",...}}
```

20th loop:

```
all_data_dict = { 0 = {"Url": "www.test20.de", "Document Title": "test20", "Releaes Date": "January 20, 2200",...}, 
    1 = {"Url": "www.test20.de", "Document Title": "test20", "Releaes Date": "January 20, 2200",...},..., 20 = {"Url": "www.test20.de", "Document Title": "test20", "Releaes Date": "January 20, 2200",...}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something must be wrong with your `scrape_doc_info` function (not sure what that might be)

The following code has your intended outcome:

```
dict1 = {"Url": "www.test1.de", "Document Title": "test1", "Releaes Date": "January 1, 2020"}
dict2 = {"Url": "www.test20.de", "Document Title": "test20", "Releaes Date": "January 20, 2020"}
list_of_dicts = [dict1, dict2]

def create_dict(link_list):
    all_data_dict = {}
    count = 0
    for link in link_list:

        all_data_dict[count] = link # this function returns the dictionary mentioned above
        count +=1
        
    return(all_data_dict)
    
my_dict = create_dict(list_of_dicts)
print(my_dict)
```

Console output:

```
{0: {'Url': 'www.test1.de', 'Document Title': 'test1', 'Releaes Date': 'January 1, 2020'}, 1: {'Url': 'www.test20.de', 'Document Title': 'test20', 'Releaes Date': 'January 20, 2020'}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I have updated the description a bit, so maybe no it more clear. When I add a print(all_data_dict) into the loop. It shows that in the first loop it will create a dictionnary with one key and values of the first link. In the second loop the dictionnary has two keys both having the same values of the second link. In the 20th loop, it will have twenty keys and each having the same values of the 20th link. So it somehow does overwrite the values from the loops before.

Comment: The problem seems, that each time the function scrape_doc_info() creates an new dictionnary, it refers always to the same dictionnary object. For example  dict1 = scrap_doc_info(linki1,,...) and dict2 = scrape_doc_info(link2,...) .   If I only create dict1 in the first step, it will have the values of link1. If I now create dict2, dict1 will as well be updated an have the same values as dict2.  Do you have any advice on this?